How to use YOLOv8 to train a model？
How to set the threshold when yolo trains the model, so that the verification error is less than the same threshold to stop training,
I flipped through Yolo's official documentation and couldn't find the relevant parameters

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you're considering early stopping to avoid overfitting of the model during training, can use 'patience' parameter, if it is set to 10, the model stops training if there is no improvement in the last 10 iterations.
